# How to secure a dir with .htaccess - PHP needs to write tokens and receive Get Requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, oauth-2.0

How do you secure a dir on apache that has a PHP file, which receives HTTP Get requests. Also, from time to time it needs to create a token file.

Currently I have...

```
<Limit POST PUT>
  deny from all
  allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
Options -Indexes
```

The above produces a 401/403 error when I use the script to save a token. Removing `Post` allows the token to be saved.

The original source of the Get request, a remote web service, has a dynamic IP so it's difficult to lock that down (although I'm all ears). But the Token comes from Facebook Oauth.

Can I lock this down further?

Comment: What is the directory structure and the URI of the file? I'm assuming the file needs to be allowed for anyone to hit?

Comment: Only one user, at a dynamic IP address. Location is like`www.example.com/helpers/facebookposter.php`

Comment: Then have them register a hostname that will update as their IP changes. That way you can just use a hostname in your apache config. https://www.dnsdynamic.org/

Comment: Oh eally? This works? The remote service has a no-ip address. Are you saying I can simply add that to the htaccess file?

Comment: I must have misunderstood, as deny from all, and allowing the no-ip address doesn't work.

Comment: It does work with a hostname or I guess a no-ip address. Make sure your DNS is working on the server. have a look at this and see if it will help. http://serverfault.com/questions/32505/apache-allow-from-rule-only-works-with-ip-addresses

Comment: "Make sure your DNS is working on the server" do you mean at the web host? Do I need them to enable something for me? I don't quite understand. I add my no-ip address to the htaccess file under "allow from" and it doesn't work. Am I missing something?